# Is it possible to have email alias in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to have email alias in Gmail?

I currently have address `foobar@gmail.com`, and I'd like to attach an email alias to the same gmail account. That is, `foobar@gmail.com` and `firstname.lastname@gmail.com` should send emails to the same box.

Is this possible? Without using other services than Gmail?

Answer (score 11):

Just open the other account and add a rule to redirect all mails to your foobar account. In `settings->accounts` you can also configure which address to use for sending mail.

Comment: And also adding certain labels to forwarded mails to immediately see where the email was addressed.

Answer (score 7):

plus addressing, as another poster mentioned, but quite a few web forms trip up on that (will tell you the address isn't valid or give some other error), so another quick and easy but perhaps little-known trick is that in Gmail (and only gmail as far as I know) the period character is basically ignored in terms of username uniqueness.

In other words, taking your examples, without having to do anything extra or set anything up beforehand, emails sent to:

```
 foobar@gmail.com 
 f.oobar@gmail.com
 f.o.obar@gmail.com 
 foo.bar@gmail.com
 foo.ba.r@gmail.com
 f.o.o.b.a.r@gmail.com
```

(and so on, for each permutation of where you put the dots)

will all arrive at the same mailbox, and you'll be able to create custom filters and rules based on each unique 'to:' address.

Comment: For what it's worth, the period DOES seem important when logging in.

Comment: the period is important if you declared your account as having one when setting it up.

Answer (score 6):

Use Gmail's "plus" addressing as explained in *[How to Use the Infinite Number of Email Addresses Gmail Gives You](https://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/how-to-use-the-infinite-number-of-email-addresses-gmail-1609458192)*.

Comment: That makes rather ugly email addresses: foobar+somethingelse@gmail.com. I'd like to choose what the alias will be.

Comment: The link in this answer is dead.

Comment: Thank you @iamnotmaynard -- I've updated the link to another guide.

Answer (score 5):

It might not be exactly what you want, but if you have your own domain name (and if you don't, you can get one for around $8 or $9 per year), you can set up a free "Google Apps" mail account on it and can have up to 50 email accounts on the domain.

See *[Get started with Google Apps for free](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html)* for more information.

--**UPDATE**-- Google Apps removed the free price plan in 2012, there is a workaround mentioned here: http://lifehacker.com/5967154/what-should-i-do-now-that-google-apps-accounts-are-no-longer-free

Answer (score 3):

Two options if the plus and period addressing tricks don't work.   In both cases, you'll need to set up two separate Google accounts -- one for each address.

If you want one address simply to be an alias for the other, go to Settings/Forwarding in gmail and forward the alias account's mail to the other mailbox.   You can also go to Settings/Accounts and Import and set it up so that you can send "from" either address.   There is also an option to reply from the To address.

If you want to have ready access to separate mailboxes, use the [multiple sign-in feature](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/topic.py?topic=28776) to allow you to switch back and forth quickly between accounts (using the drop-down next to your email address).

Answer (score 0):

For example if your email is YOURNAME@gmail.com any emails to YOURNAME+nots@gmail.com will be delivered to your account.

If email address is xxx@gmail.com

xxx+nots@gmail.com

xxx+ae@gmail.com

xxx+bbc@gmail .com

will be delivered to xxx@gmail.com